# Service Fabric Actors in a separate AppDomain

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm contemplating a design in which "DynamicActors" are able to load and execute arbitrary code from a given file share in a dynamically created AppDomain. Something like this pseudocode

```
class DynamicActor: Actor, IDynamicActor

  Task ExecuteAsync(string assemblyName, string typeName)      
    AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(...)
    appDomain.SetData("AssemblyName", assemblyName)
    appDomain.SetData("TypeName", typeName)
    appDomain.DoCallBack(<load the type and execute a predefined / interface method>)
```

The rationale is to be able to update the dynamically loaded code frequently without the need of upgrading the DynamicActors service.

Is this a good idea in general?

Can the dynamically loaded code in the isolated AppDomain use the SF runtime, for example create an actor proxy and call its methods?

Thanks,

Palo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considering Vaclav’s answer, I’ve decided to go to the “all Service Fabric” route described below. Before that, let me tell you a bit more about the application scenario:

- There will be **hundreds** of assemblies implementing unattended ETL-type “tasks”.
- The tasks will execute periodically with duration in the range of seconds, a minute at most.
- The task assemblies will have to be versioned separately (including their dependencies) and they will be versioned frequently.
- The task assemblies must not have dependencies on SF assemblies.

The goal is really to use the Service Fabric cluster to execute any code reachable through a file share.

I’ve put up a sample proof-of-concept solution on GitHub - https://github.com/PaloMraz/ServiceFabricDynamicTaskExecution.

**Note**: In the following discussion, the term “task” means any public class with public default constructor exposing public method with the following signature:

```
Task<string> ExecuteAsync(string parameters)
```

The sample solution consists of the following components:

**TaskExecutorActors** service containing the TaskExecutorActor actor with single ExecuteTaskAsync method:

```
Task<string> ExecuteTaskAsync(string taskAssemblyPath, string taskClassName, string taskParameters);
```

The implementation uses the Activator.CreateInstanceFrom API to instantiate the class in the specified assembly and then calls the ExecuteAsync method with the parameters specified.

**TaskExecutorGateway** is a stateless service that exposes Web API HTTP endpoints to be called from outside the cluster.

**TaskExecutorClientLib** is a class library containing TaskExecutorClient class with methods for easily calling the TaskExecutorGateway HTTP endpoints:

```
Task<string> ExecuteTaskAsync(string taskAssemblyPath, string taskClassName, string taskParameters)
```

The implementation of this method inside TaskExecutorGateway uses the **directory name** of the passed-in taskAssemblyPath to create a unique instance of the TaskExecutorActors service to load and execute tasks from assemblies in the directory.

Once loaded by the TaskExecutorActors service process, the task assemblies are locked and cannot be replaced. In order to replace the assemblies, the TaskExecutorClient exposes another method:

```
Task<string> UnloadTaskAssembliesAsync(string assembliesFolderPath)
```

The implementation (inside TaskExecutorGateway) simply deletes the on-demand created “directory-bound” TaskExecutorActors service tearing down its process and freeing up the loaded assemblies.

The solution contains two sample task assemblies and a **TaskExecutorTestConsole** console project with some code excersising the whole infrastructure.

*Please note*: The TaskExecutorGateway exposes the Web API through port 80, so make sure to change this in the ServiceManifest.xml and the TaskExecutorTestConsole sample code if you have other applications in your local dev cluster that already listen on port 80.

What do you thing about this SF usage pattern?

Comment: So you group assemblies into directories, each directory gets a service instance, and within each service instance you dynamically load an assembly and execute it in an actor? Cool! Service instances are a good choice because you can dynamically create and delete instances as needed, so you have complete control over scale. I have also seen patterns where a service instance manages execution of a single assembly, which is useful for longer-running operations. In your case, actors work well for individual assemblies because it's much faster to create an actor instance than a service instance.

Comment: Where do you store the assemblies?

Comment: This is for on-premises deployment, so I've been planning to use a file share. I've also experimented with `Assembly.UnsafeLoadFrom` to serve the dynamic assemblies over HTTP and so far it's working fine provided that the web server returns the appropriate headers for the assembly binaries (`Cache-Control: max-age=0, private` worked for me).

Comment: One option to consider is setting up another Service Fabric service that just hosts the assemblies. You can put the assemblies in the service's Data Package and have the service expose an API for fetching the assemblies. This way, you'll have versioned snapshots of the assemblies, and everything will be self-contained in your SF cluster (imagine you move your system, you won't need to set up a fileshare or HTTP server - just redeploy your applications).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Vaclav. The system I’ve been trying to design will be very dynamic: Developers should be able to just copy a new / revised task .dll to the designated directory, then a monitoring service will note the change and somehow recycle the associated directory-scoped service instance (perhaps by calling `FabricClient.ServiceManager.Delete/CreateServiceAsync`).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound like a good idea if you just want a way to upgrade your actor service code. Application upgrades are a core scenario in Service Fabric and Service Fabric does it well. If you designed your own with dynamic assembly loading, you'll have to think about versioning, health monitoring, safe rolling upgrades, rollbacks, etc., all of which Service Fabric already does.

If you're looking for a "plug-in" model where users can run plug-ins, I might suggest looking at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that's designed for this purpose.